# How to remove non hierarchical data from a table

Tags: hierarchy

I have a table like the following one.
Parent and child fieldS are in a one (parent) to many (child) relation except for FRANCE.
FRANCE has got two parents: EMEA and APAC.
What I need is to keep only one relation for FRANCE (the one with the highest customers count) and put the others into a log table.

Please could you help?
Many thanks in advance.

Alberto

Original table
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| RowID | parent | child  | customers count |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|     1 | EMEA   | FRANCE |               5 |
|     2 | EMEA   | ITALY  |               2 |
|     3 | AMER   | USA    |               1 |
|     4 | AMER   | BRASIL |               5 |
|     5 | APAC   | FRANCE |               1 |
|     6 | APAC   | JAPAN  |               3 |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+

the final result should be:

Master data table

+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| RowID | parent | child  | customers count |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|     1 | EMEA   | FRANCE |               5 |
|     2 | EMEA   | ITALY  |               2 |
|     3 | AMER   | USA    |               1 |
|     4 | AMER   | BRASIL |               5 |
|     6 | APAC   | JAPAN  |               3 |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+

log table

+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
| RowID | parent | child  | customers count |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+
|     5 | APAC   | FRANCE |               1 |
+-------+--------+--------+-----------------+

Comment: Please read [mre] and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples